# Синхронизация изменений с сервера и локалок в одну учетку

Tags: git, gitlab

Здравствуйте.
Ведётся разработка сайта, есть несколько человек, участвующих в этом, каждый на своей локалке. Создан репозиторий на GitLab. 
Проблема в том, что сайт активно работает с файлами, и нужно перед внесением своих изменений забирать изменения с сайта.
Каким образом можно организовать работу, в каком порядке и можно ли как-то упростить? Что-то совсем запутался...

Comment: видимо, нужно разделить Ваши файлы и серверные файлы. Иначе запутаетесь

Comment: каким образом это сделать? добавить в игнор не вариант, так как люди могут работать с системными файлами, и эти файлы могут быть изменены из админки сайта (хранят настройки, шаблоны в зависимости от параметров и тд), то есть, и то и то может быть перезаписано всеми

Comment: как я бы делал. Отдельно лежат файлы сайта и отдельно файлы, которые могут меняться с админок. Если теперь, нужно брать к примеру конфиг, то вначале загружаем один, а потом поверху другой.